# How to throw Exceptions not mandatorily require catch

Tags: java, exception, throw

```
public class Action {

    public Action(ActionName name) {
        this(name, "");
    }

    public Action(ActionName name, String...args) {
        ...
        act();
    }

    public Action(String url, String paramStr) {
        ...
        act();
    }

    private void act() {
        try {
            response = KanHttpUtil.post(url, paramStr);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.toConsole(ex.getMessage()); 
            throw ex;  // Actually I can't throw it until I surround it with another try-catch
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I have this action class. It will be called frequently. I need to throw exception if something wrong with the http post. However I don't want to write try-catch around every call, neither do those calls need to catch the Exception. Action is always called by construction method, but try-catch in the first contruction method is not feasible.

Now I am just confused what to do.

---

I want to make this change to my code

```
throw new RuntimeException();
```

or should I extend the RuntimeExeption to MyException and throw it?

And may I catch it when I call Action(ActionName name)?

---

As required by Ben, I am going to explain some details of the program. The `act()` in Action is the core method in the class, it post a http request and parse the response to some level. I call it in constructor because it is always called and have no task to return. Instead, I have `getResponseCode()`, `getResponseData()` to obtain the infomation. I found it simple to make this call, `int code = new Action(ActionName.A, paramStr).getResponseCode()`. So failure happens if http post fails or the reponse is not in predicted form.

here is the source code of KanHttpUtil

```
public class KanHttpUtil {

    private static String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36";

    public static String post(String url, String paramStr) throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnection con = null;

        // request
        if (!url.startsWith("http"))
            url = "http://" + Info.getHost() + url;
        if (!paramStr.contains("verno"))
            paramStr = paramStr + "&api_verno=1";
        if (!paramStr.contains("token"))
            paramStr = paramStr + "&api_token=" + Info.getToken();
        try {
            con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            con.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            con.setReadTimeout(30000); 
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setUseCaches(false);            
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            osw.write(paramStr.replace("_", "%5F").replace(",", "%2C"));
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (con != null) {
                con.disconnect();
            }
        }

        // response
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String temp;
            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(temp);
                buffer.append("\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Throw the exception down the stack.

Comment: You most certainly shouldn't catch an exception at every stage. Only catch it if you _handle_ it in some way. The problem is Java has checked exceptions so if you throw an exception that doesn't inherit from `RuntimeException` you usually need to add `throws MyException` (where `MyException` is the type thrown) to the method signature.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Down the Stack? What do you mean? BTW, I solve the problem yesterday by restrict encode to utf-8 in FileInputStream (if you remember it

Comment: I mean in the method call stack. Just declare your method as `throws Exception` and let the calling code handle it. (I'm glad to hear it.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I would not do that, because it is such a big project and makes coding untidy. I'd rather follow the others' suggestion to throw RuntimeException.

Comment: @bijiDango In most languages, functions are "stacked" upon each other, if you have three functions: `a,b and c` and you call `a`, `a` calls `b` and `b` calls `c` in your computer you have a stack (a pile) of function calls (frames) where `a` is at the bottom, `b` is above it and `c` is above that, this is how the computer 'remembers' where to return to when it is done executing code. What Sotirios means is that you can catch it at any of those stages. In fact, even this site is called "StackOverflow" which is an error you get if have too many calls and they fill up this entire stack.

Comment: Also, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack . @SotiriosDelimanolis `throws Exception` might be an extremely poor solution here, depending on what bijiDango is actually doing.

Comment: If you throw a RuntimeException, you will need to *catch* a RuntimeException which means you could be catching *many* things that you really shouldn't be (and for very good reason).  What are you *really* trying to solve as a problem?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thank you for the explanation, and that solution is indeed not I want in this situation.

Comment: @bijiDango can you show us the source code of `KanHttpUtil.post(url, paramStr);` and also _describe in words_ what `act` does? (What I mean by does is - what has to happen in order to it to succeed, what is considered "failure" and what is "normal" for it, what other methods like the Action overloads that use it are also an interesting part here - note that generally constructors usually should not be doing a lot of background work (like making hTTP requests) implicitly since you usually only expect a constructor to initialize things.

Comment: It appears KanHttpUtil.post catches all exceptions internally, so you can remove `throws Exception` from that method's signature.  Then your Action class doesn't need any catch blocks at all.  Of course, whether you should be catching Exception inside the `post` method is another matter.  (In my opinion, you should not.)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways I can think of:

- Think about where you would like to throw your exception and handle it. You might want to catch and throw it somewhere lower in the call hierarchy. A good scenario for such approach is when, let's say, you are reading a text file line by line, and you want to simply ignore a line if it is bad (by some definition of 'bad' for your usecase). In that case if you apply a try-catch within the reader and make it `continue` right after the current line, that would a be a good approach.
- Alternatively, you can use a subclass of `RunTimeException` iff you are sure that there is no guarantee what you can promise to do if some exception occurs. Using Runtime exceptions is, for most cases, not a great idea. Since these are unchecked exceptions, one does not need to catch them explicitly as part of the contract - this can lead to situations where a loose coding practice can bring the system/service down because one did not plan for an exception that got thrown from within the RuntimeException block. This is exactly what happened with me once.

Happy coding!

Comment: Why is it making him wrap the call with a `catch` and not letting it throw? Why is using `RuntimeException` for most cases not a great idea?

Comment: @Benjamin: Since these are unchecked exceptions, one does not need to catch them explicitly as part of the contract - this can lead to situations where a loose coding practice can bring the system/service down because one did not plan for an exception that got thrown from within the `RuntimeException` block. This is exactly what happened with me once. What's your thought?

Comment: @user721998 Actually I have 2 major use of Action. The first is for user operation, I don't want to do catch here since it bring no big damage. But when I want to make a autoscript, catching exceptions becomes important.

Comment: @user721998 the point was to edit that into the answer, not comment to me :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: This is the first time I am answering someone else's question here on Stackoverflow. Pardon my ignorance, Benjamin! :)

Comment: @bijiDango: You can simply do nothing (or rather just log for your record) for the first scenario, and really catch the exception and write the exception handling code for the second time.